# Where to find RabbitMQ Management HTTP API history of changes?

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ management plugin [documentation page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) there is a [link to latest HTTP API documentation](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.4/priv/www/api/index.html). I see that in latest documentation there are added new endpoints for example `/api/vhost-limits`. (At least on my local installation 3.6.5 it isn't defined.)
Is it possible somewhere to find history of changes to management HTTP API? With which version specific endpoint was defined and (or) modified? 
I only was able to find [RabbitMQ Changelog](https://www.rabbitmq.com/changelog.html), but there I wasn't able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API page is located [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/blob/master/priv/www/api/index.html). You may be able to find the information you need via the `git log` or `git blame` commands (or via the web history).

Also, please note that `3.6.5` is well over a year old.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to digest v3.7.* documentation links using this link pattern:
`https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.*/priv/www/api/index.html`
where * is last number in version.

And previous Management HTTP API documentation links where based on bit different pattern:
`https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_vX_Y_Z/priv/www/api/index.html`
 where X,Y,Z are version numbers (f.e.: https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_15/priv/www/api/index.html.)

Thanks to @[Luke Bakken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466825/luke-bakken) for given mailing list link, where I found a clue.

The earliest documented version which I found is [2.6.0](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v2_6_0/priv/www/api/index.html). That smells a little bit like archaeology, but maybe someone will find this information useful.